# Align row texts in a listview

Tags: android, android-layout

The row of my listview has 3 texts. What I want to do is to align all the rows texts vertically. I tried that using the TableLayout view for the row, and I've set the width for the first and third cell's as a constant. I'm not very happy using constants because of the porting issues. Is it possible to align these texts without in another way? Here is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ingredient_amount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.one2snap.littlechef.android.main.ui.views.AmienneTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ingredient_title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LinearLayout and apply a Weight to each Text view.  If you give each text a weight of 1, then they will each take a third of the screen equally. If you gave one text a weight of 2 and the others a weight of 1, then the 2 will take half of the screen the other two will use a fourth, etc.  [See here under LinearLayout for more info.](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html)

Comment: Using LinearLayout and weight doesn't help. It uses the remainig space, not the absolute space. So the second and third text views cannot be aligned.

Comment: Using LinearLayout and the weight means using the extra space, so it doesn't create views with equal widths.

Comment: I must say I'm surprised that there's not more input on how to do this kind of thing. In my work I've encountered many situations where I need to display rows of data in a neat tabular format but you'd think that nobody does that on Android devices judging by the amount of literature I've been able to uncover on the subject.